# How to change the image location across an entire PHP site

Tags: php, cdn

I have a website written in PHP. I have a lot of images. Decided that i want to go with a CDN. So the CDN is located on another domain - xxx.azureedge.net (Azure CDN). Now, i need to rewrite all the links from  (example)

```
/images/items/xxxx.png
```

to

```
https://xxx.azureedge.net/images/items/xxx.png
```

How do i do this on a massive scale so i don't have to go to every single entry and manually change it. I can do with an app such as "search and replace" but i wished to do it via PHP

Comment: Do you have an IDE like PHP Storm ? because you can Search and replace in all files with regexp !

Comment: A sort of hacky solution is to use your webserver's rewrite capabilities to make all image extensions redirect to the CDN, though how you do this depends on the webserver you're using. This would only be a transitional solution until you've replaced all instances with the correct links

Comment: You should have a function like getFullImagePath($image) on every src attribute. Then you are always flexible.

Comment: use visual studio code ide for search and replace

Comment: Any kind of PHP solution will just unnecessarily complicate things. Search and replace is the way to go, don't overthink it.

Comment: I was under the impression that search and replace is a brutish way of doing and the elegant way would be with PHP. Maybe getFullImagePath($image) is an idea